# How to inline destructure nested optional properties from an object in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

I have the following code of a type User that has optional type `Address` that I want to desctructure in a single line. However, when I try, I am getting an error saying:

> Property 'street' does not exist on type 'Address | undefined'

[Click here to see the Typescript playground of the code provided bellow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=15&ssc=38&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATlAvFA3gKCjghgcwgC4oA7AVwFsAjJAbmzwBMnEI44B%20EgQRbY4MAvpkyhIUPq3ZxUGRnGBsIwblEWIAlqXzDRAYwD2pRVHIJEJeEjlY8hEgCZHAGka5%20MkuhEjMRk2AMAggXKA9pDm8NCBUhITlzJCA)

```
type User = {
 age: number;
 address?: Address;
}

type Address = {
 street?: string;
}

const user: User = {
 age: 22,
 address: {}
}

const {age, address: {street}} = user
```

Here the **street** does not exist on type `Address | undefined`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to initialize the `address` in your `const`.

Like this:

```
const {age, address : {street} = {}} = user;
```

[PlaygroundLink](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=15&ssc=45&pln=15&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATlAvFA3gKCjghgcwgC4oA7AVwFsAjJAbmzwBMnEI44B%20EgQRbY4MAvpkyhIUPq3ZxUGRnGBsIwblEWIAlqXzDRAYwD2pRVHIJEJeEjlY8hElABMTgDSNc-GY-QiRmIxNgDAIIVyhPaQ4oEnQNCBUhWyEktHN6IA)